# Why am I unable to download Mavericks from the App Store?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I am running Mountain Lion. But unfortunately, I'm having trouble downloading Mavericks Installer from the App Store.

Here is what happens: I search for Mavericks in the App Store, it shows Mavericks. I click on Upgrade. Then it asks for my Apple ID and password. As I enter the credentials, after a few seconds, the same thing happens, again asking for my Apple ID and password and nothing happens.

If my password was wrong, it should have shown a message indicating incorrect Apple ID/password.

What can I do to resolve this issue?